# Returning from method disposes corectly the object?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement, try-finally

If you use the `using` method instead of lets say `FileStream.Close();`, will the class dispose correctly?

```
private static string GetString()
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
         return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
private static string GetString()
{
    string toReturn = "";           

    FileStream fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open)
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)

    toReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();

    sr.Close();
    fs.Close();

    return toReturn;
}
```

or to:

```
private static string GetString()
{
    FileStream fs;
    StreamReader sr;

    try
    {
        string toReturn = "";          

        fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open)
        sr = new StreamReader(fs)

        toReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();

        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();

        return toReturn;
    }
    finally
    {
       if(sr != null)
           sr.Close();

       if(fs != null)
           fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How difficult is it to locate documentation on C#s `using` by using a search engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667111/some-advanced-questions-on-the-using-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code generated from a `using` statement is very similar to your second example (the biggest difference being that it calls `IDisposable.Dispose` instead of `Close`).  It will always properly dispose of the objects, whether the method exits through a `return` or a thrown exception.

In case you're curious, this is the C# code without `using`s that compiles to the same IL as your example with `using`s:

```
private static string GetString()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open);
    try
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        try
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null)
                ((IDisposable)sr).Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
            ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how it compiles - the declaration is outside of the `try`, the assignment is inside (otherwise, there's no way to enter the `try` block with `fs` non-null, in which case why check for non-null in the `finally`.

Comment: I must disagree.  I'm looking at each decompiled in ILSpy. http://ilspy.net/  The only differences are some `nop` operations (strange that there are any, I'm building in Release mode with VS2012; but that's beside the point).  The non-null check is included because you could have done `using (FileStream fs = null)` or, more likely, `using (var fs = GetSomething())`, which could've returned null.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look `using` statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx

It should be equivalent to:

```
FileStream fs = null;

try
{
    fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader sr = null;
    try
    {
        sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        toReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return toReturn;
    }
    finally
    {
       if(sr != null)
           sr.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    if(fs != null)
        fs.Dispose();
}
```

Inside `Dispose` method, it will call `Close` stream.

Comment: That's not how it compiles - the declaration is outside of the `try`, the assignment is inside (otherwise, there's no way to enter the `try` block with `fs` non-null, in which case why check for non-null in the `finally`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: that's correct

Answer (score 0):

If it implements `IDisposable` it will be closed properly when the using block is exited.